# How to link JavaDoc to different class?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm trying to write a javadoc which displays the javadoc from another method, like:

```
private List<Object> list;

/**
 * {@link list#indexOf(Object)} 
 */
int getMyIndex(Object o) {
   return list.indexOf(o);
}
```

This would give me a javadoc link when I use my `getMyIndex()` method. But what I want is that eclipse just actually shows(!) the javadoc from the method that I referenced in `@link`.

Of course that's not what link is for. Link does what is should do in this case.

But what do I have to use to somehow "import" a foreign javadoc there?

Comment: I don't think so... the closest thing is {@inheritDoc} but it is for 'importing' the parent method's main description.

Comment: Yes I also thought about that, but as you said only suitable if a class extends another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there isn't any such tag or functionality as far as I know. Refer the [javadoc tag list for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags).

From the link

```
    Tag      |  Introduced in JDK/SDK
-----------------------------------
    @author       1.0
    {@code}       1.5
    {@docRoot}    1.3
    @deprecated   1.0
    @exception    1.0
    {@inheritDoc} 1.4
    {@link}       1.2
    {@linkplain}  1.4
    {@literal}    1.5
    @param        1.0
    @return       1.0
    @see          1.0
    @serial       1.2
    @serialData   1.2
    @serialField  1.2
    @since        1.1
    @throws       1.2
    {@value}      1.4
    @version      1.0
```